# Sorting an ObservableCollection<BusinessObject> using a custom sort order

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

In WPF, I have an ObservableCollection, which I need to sort in an arbitrary custom order, meaning it's not just A-Z, the items need to be individually movable.

The BusinessObject has a field of ID, which is a string GUID. Can I have a Dictionary, storing these GUIDs and their assigned positions in the sort order, and if so, how can I apply a sort order from a separate Dictionary?

In short, I want to be able to have a manipulatable sort order for the ObservableCollection, stored in a separate object.

Comment: Try to do that overriding the ObservableCollection<T> class making your own with sort capabilities :D

Comment: How critical is the separate object containing the sort order? Do you want a completely custom sort order, and you don't want to/can't store that custom order within your business object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ICollectionView:

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(businessObjects);
view.SortDescriptions.Add( SortDescription("NameOfPropertyToSortBy",ListSortDirection.Ascending ));
```

Then expose and bind to the view value. Although, actually there is binding black magic under the covers and you don't even need to change the bound collection but it's much more maintainable if you do.

Comment: I did try to do it this way, but ICollectionView doesn't seem to allow me to move individual items up or down.

Comment: You can use a custom sort by implementing IComparer and assign it to the CustomSort property on ICollectionView.

Comment: That's a good point. I could have this in my separate sorting class, and have methods to apply it to an ObservableCollection.

Comment: Exactly. Then the sorting is decoupled and nice and testable.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but I've encountered a similar problem where it was important that the `ObservableCollection<T>` was not recreated, and that the objects in the collection were moved using the `ObservableCollection.Move()` method (as opposed to removed and inserted) to their new index. This was to facilitate WPF fluid move animations, etc.

In that case, I created an extension method that allowed you to pass an `IEnumerable<T>` of objects in the preferred sort order, and have the `ObservableCollection<T>` move everything into place.

It's very simple, so I post it here in case it's of any use to anyone:

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void MatchSort<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> collectionToMatchSortOrder)
    {
        int newIndex = 0;

        foreach (var item in collectionToMapSortOrder.Where(item => collection.Contains(item)))
        {
            collection.Move(collection.IndexOf(item), newIndex);
            newIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This is far from foolproof, as it ideally relies on all objects present in the observable collection to be present in the `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: This will help me, and certainly others too, upvoted!